# How can I switch an applications starting activity based on a decision point?

Tags: android

I have a decision point at the start of my application. The result of the decision point will determine which activity I launch first.

My question is, how can I toggle which activity is first launched in an application, based on the outcome of a decision point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your DecisionActivity class's `onCreate` method:

```
if (condition) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class));
} else {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
}
finish();
```

so basically you have a dummy activity which launches the appropriate one and then immediately closes.